# Velocity Template Not Found With Classpath

Tags: java, velocity

I cannot seem to get access to my velocity templates when I switch to the "classpath" resource loader.  I've tried putting a templates directory on /WEB-INF/classes/templates,  /WEB-INF/templates, creating a templates.jar in /WEB-INF/lib.  None of them work.  Any ideas?  Permissions on those files are all correct.

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.setProperty("runtime.log.logsystem.class", "org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.log.CommonsLogLogSystem");

/*
// Works fine:
p.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "file");
p.setProperty("file.resource.loader.path", "/path/to/templates");
*/

// Cannot find template with this:
p.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "classpath");
p.setProperty("class.resource.loader.class", ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName());
p.setProperty("resourceLoaderPath", "/WEB-INF/classes/templates");

org.apache.velocity.app.Velocity.init(p);

template = org.apache.velocity.app.Velocity.getTemplate("confirmation_html.vm");
```

Answer (score 8):

This i how i have done it in the past. It has worked, albeit may not be the best way to get it working. Assuming that you have a */webapps/WEB-INF/* structure,

```
 Properties prop = new Properties();
 String absolutePath=new File(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("").getFile()).getParentFile().getParentFile().getPath();//this goes to webapps directory
 prop.put("file.resource.loader.path", absolutePath+"/WEB-INF/classes/templates");
 Velocity.init(prop);
 Template t=Velocity.getTemplate("confirmation_html.vm");
```

p1ng

Answer (score 1):

IIRC,  WEB-INF/clases is a root of classpath three, so you can just try "templates/" or "/templates"

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  So, stick my templates in WEB-INF/classes/ and then set resourceLoaderPath to "templates/"?  I'm not even sure resourceLoaderPath does anything.  I just saw it in another example.

Answer (score 0):

This is painful. If you put in the classpath then the development becomes hell, since the servlet container would reload the webapp every time you make a change in the velocity templates.

I would recommend using the org.apache.velocity.tools.view.WebappResourceLoader, which makes development much easier by not requiring the files to be in the classpath and also allows you to do relative includes.

You can also check my post about this: [Spring-mvc + Velocity + DCEVM](http://blog.rafaelsanches.com/2012/02/02/spring-mvc-velocity-dcevm/)